# How to "wrap" <Route> component so that it can be used inside <Router> in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I created `<RequireAuthRoute>` which simply either returns its children or navigates to `/login`. However the way it is being used doesn't satisfy me. Take a look at this fragment:

```
<Route
  path=''
  element={
    <RequireAuthRoute>
      <Explorer />
    </RequireAuthRoute>
  }
/>
```

So yes - technically it works but what I wanted to do is to create wrapper for `<Route>` component so it would end up looking like this:

```
<ProtectedRoute path='' element={<Explorer/>}/>
```

Whats blocking me is `react-router` itself which tells me that `<Router>` direct child can only be `<Route>` component. Any workarounds?

Comment: That's how wrapper components work in RRDv6. Custom route components are invalid in RRDv6. If you don't want to wrap each individual component with `RequireAuthRoute` then convert it to a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes) instead of a wrapper component. Do you need help with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Custom route components aren't valid in `react-router-dom@6` like what was commonly used in v5.

```
<ProtectedRoute path='....' element={<Explorer />} />
```

The above will throw an invariant violation because ***only*** `Route` and `React.Fragment` are valid children of the `Routes` component, and `Route` components can only be rendered directly by the `Routes` component or another `Route` component.

If using wrapper components such as `RequireAuthRoute` is insufficient:

```
<Route
  path='....'
  element={
    <RequireAuthRoute>
      <Explorer />
    </RequireAuthRoute>
  }
/>
```

Then the other common v6 pattern is to use [layout routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes) that render an `Outlet` component for nested routes instead of a `children` prop.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthLayout = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  ... business logic ...

  return isAuthenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login replace state={{ from: location }} />
};
```

Then wrap and render the routes you want to protect with this layout route:

```
<Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
  <Route path='....' element={<Explorer />} />
  ... other protected routes ...
</Route>
... other unprotected routes ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

**Option 1**. Use a curried function to wrap each lazy loaded Route's element in a Suspense component. This avoids having to do so in each Route's element prop.

```
import { Suspense } from "react";

export const Loadable = (Component: any) => (props: any) => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading</p>}>
      <Component {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

**Option 2**: Declare routes via data instead of using the Route component. Use a custom function (`createRoutesWithSuspenseWrappers` in this example) to generate each Route, wrapped in Suspense.

```
const routes = createRoutesWithSuspenseWrappers([
  { path: '/', element: <Root /> },
  // ...
]);

createBrowserRouter(routes);
```